# Dropping rows in a correlation DataFrame with 2 while loops (python)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, while-loop, data-science, correlation

*Edit, I have now provided a base dataframe to copy/paste (it's my first post, I am learning how to proceed!)*

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

random.seed(10)
randomlist_list =[]

for i in range(10):
    randomlist = []
    for j in range(10):
        n = random.randint(1,30)
        randomlist.append(n)
    randomlist_list.append(randomlist)
df_ml= pd.DataFrame(randomlist_list , columns=['Y', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E','F', 'G','H','I'])
df_ml_corr = df_ml.corr()
```

I have currently a correlation DataFrame and I am looking to drop columns and rows whenever 2 input columns (i.e: "A", "F") are more correlated than the input with the output variable (i.e: "A", "Y").

**Here is my current code (to be applied to a bigger matrix):**

```
corr_columns = df_ml_corr.columns
loopcount = df_ml.corr().columns.shape[0]
i = 1

#while statement i column index
while i < loopcount:
   j=1   
   #for loop j row index
   while j < loopcount:
       if i==j:
           j+=1
       elif abs(df_ml_corr.iloc[j,i]) > abs(df_ml_corr.iloc[0,i]):
           df_ml_corr.drop(df_ml_corr.columns[j], axis='index', inplace=True)
           df_ml_corr.drop(df_ml_corr.columns[j], axis=1, inplace=True)
           corr_columns = df_ml_corr.columns
           loopcount = df_ml.corr().columns.shape[0]
       else:
           j+=1
   i+=1
```

I also added an if statement to avoid dropping the row i=j which is correlation to itself (=1), and not add 1 to j if I am deleting any row.

**At this stage, the error popping is the following:**

> --->   elif abs(df_ml_corr.iloc[j,i]) > abs(df_ml_corr.iloc[0,i]):
> **IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds**

Any insights on what I'm doing wrongly?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; we need your question to be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Answer (score 0):

Let's catch all the bugs in your code:

Bug #1: missing `j+=1` in elif block, resulting in an infinite loop

Bug #2: the var `loopcount = df_ml.corr().columns.shape[0]` is wrongly assigned. Since you want to count the number of columns, simply use `len(df_ml_corr.columns)`

Bug #3: because you are going to increment i & j by 1 to do some operation, the end condition `loopcount` should be 1 less

So the final code should be:

```
loopcount = len(df_ml_corr.columns)
i = 0

#while statement i column index
while i < loopcount-1:   #end condition
    j=0
    #for loop j row index
    while j < loopcount-1:   #end condition
        if i==j:
            j+=1
        elif abs(df_ml_corr.iloc[j,i]) > abs(df_ml_corr.iloc[0,i]):
            df_ml_corr.drop(df_ml_corr.columns[j], axis='index', inplace=True)
            df_ml_corr.drop(df_ml_corr.columns[j], axis=1, inplace=True)
            loopcount = len(df_ml_corr.columns)   #count the number of columns
            j+=1   #end condition
        else:
            j+=1
    i+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your insights ! The code is working better, but I identified some remaining errors (I am trying to fix them currently, if you have any additional ideas, that's great)

**Using the example dataframe, the code should:**

- Step 1: go over column A => drop column F
- Step 2: go over column B => drop column C, D, H, I
- Step 3: go over column E => pass
- Step 4: go over column G => pass

However, the outdated code has 2 flaws:

1. The new elif block does not take in account the fact that it deleted a row, thus df_ml_corr.iloc[j,i] actually refers to the row that was previously bellow (that's why I did not implement j+=1)
2. Because it skips some rows, the code will sometimes delete previous columns (when it happens, it will advance to the next column without totally processing the rest of the column)

**In the example, the updated code does the following:**

- Step 1: i=1 (A), j=6 => Drop F (loopcount-1 = 8)
- Step 2: i=2 (B), j=3 => Drop C (loopcount-1 = 7) and ignore column D which is now at j=3
- Step 3: i=2 (B), j=6 => Drop H (loopcount-1 = 6) and ignore column I which is now at j=6 (and loopcount-1 is reached anyway)
- Step 4: i=3 (D), j=2 => Drop B (loopcount-1 = 5) thus i=3 is now looping over a different column
- Step 5: i=3 (E), nothing more happens
- Step 6: i=4 (G), j=1 => Drop A , thus i=4 is now looping over the next column
- Step 7: i=4 (I), j=2 => Drop E

To fix it, I tried to change the elif block with j-=1 to loop again backward (which should fall into either the if or else block until everything is cleaned) but without any success.